# How to import a shared object symbol that is an array using dlsym

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I'm trying to manually import symbols from `libncurses.so`. This works fine for function pointers and normal variables like `stdscr` or `COLORS`. However, `ncurses.h` also defines a global array named `acs_map`:

```
extern NCURSES_EXPORT_VAR(chtype) acs_map[];
```

How can I import this using `dlsym()`? My problem here is that `acs_map` is an array, not a pointer so I'm not sure if it's allowed to do something like this:

```
chtype **ptr = dlsym(lib, "acs_map");
chtype *acs_map = *ptr;
```

But I think I have to use a pointer somehow because I can't assign a new value to an array variable, can I? So what's the recommended way to import `acs_map` using `dlsym()`?

Comment: I think just `chtype *acs_map = dlsym(lib, "acs_map");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since arrays decay to a pointer to their first member, you can use a pointer type to refer to the array object.

```
chtype *ptr = dlsym(lib, "acs_map");
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can stuff that pointer into the array type that is declared in `ncurses.h` and is referenced in lots of macros? I can't declare a `chtype *acs_map` global because it clashes with the `ncurses.h` declaration of `chtype acs_map[]`. Is there any way to stuff the imported `acs_map` into the `chtype acs_map[]` or do I have to modify `ncurses.h` so that it uses `chtype *acs_map`?

Comment: @Andreas if you're including nurses.h then you shouldn't be using `dlsym`.  You should be dynamically linking with `-lncurses`